# Max salary of employee with name using MapReduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

Suppose I have a file in HDFS with the below data:

```
EmpId,EmpName,Dept,Salary

121,Raj,Dept1,8000
122,Kiran,Dept2,6000 
123,John,Dept3,9000
```

Using MapReduce I want to get only the `Salary` and `EmpName` of the employee with the max `Salary`

I was able to get the max `Salary` but not able to get the corresponding `EmpName`. I am able to get only the max `Salary` by keeping the empty key in my `map` class and `Math.max()` in my `reduce` class. When I keep the key as `EmpName` then it is displaying all the salaries of unique employees.

## My Mapreduce code

File : `test.csv`

```
121,Raj,Dept1,8000
122,Kiran,Dept2,6000 
123,John,Dept3,9000
```

```
public static class MyMap extends Mapper<LongWritable,Text,Text,IntWritable>    
 {  
  public void map(LongWritable k,Text v, Context con)throws IOException, InterruptedException  
  {  
   String line = v.toString();  
   String[] w=line.split(",");  
   int sal=Integer.parseInt(w[3]);  
   con.write(new Text("Raj"), new IntWritable(sal));  
   }  
 }

 public static class MyRed extends Reducer<Text,IntWritable,IntWritable,Text>  
 {  
  public void reduce(Text k, Iterable<IntWritable> vlist, Context con)
  throws IOException , InterruptedException  
     {  
      int max=0;  
      for(IntWritable v:vlist)  
   {
      max=Math.max(max, v.get());   
   }  

   con.write(new IntWritable(max), new Text());  
  }
```

Output :

```
9000
```

Here I need the output to be:

```
9000 John
```

Please let me know how to get this output.

Answer (score 1):

In your `map` phase save the entry with the highest salary and write it to the context during `cleanup`. This results in only one output per mapper which is the entry with the highest salary those mappers have seen. When you output the entry you could just output the whole text line. In your **single** `reduce` phase you then split the text line again and determine the max. salary of the sent text lines - which are not that many as each mapper just sent a single item.

[Here](https://github.com/adamjshook/mapreducepatterns/blob/master/MRDP/src/main/java/mrdp/ch3/TopTenDriver.java) is an example in Java for determining the top 10 users based on their reputation. You should be able to get the idea from it.

BTW: You requested code but didn't mention in which language and also didn't show any previous attempts by yourself, therefore I just point you to the example mentioned above.

Comment: Thankyou DAXaholic, i have edited my post please see it once

Answer (score 0):

pls try the following code. you will get the results.

```
public static class MyMap extends Mapper<LongWritable,Text,Text,Text>    
 {  
  public void map(LongWritable k,Text v, Context con)throws IOException, InterruptedException  
  {  
   String line = v.toString();  
   String[] w=line.split(",");  
   int sal=Integer.parseInt(w[3]);  
   string name=Integer.parseInt(w[1]);
   con.write(new Text(name), new Text(name+","+sal));  
   }  
 } 

 public static class MyRed extends Reducer<Text,Text,IntWritable,Text>  
 {  
  public void reduce(Text k, Iterable<Text> vlist, Context con)
  throws IOException , InterruptedException  
     {  
      int max=0;  
      for(Text v:vlist)  
   {
        String line = v.toString();  
        String[] w=line.split(",");  
        int sal=Integer.parseInt(w[1]); 
        max=Math.max(max, sal);
   }  
   con.write(new IntWritable(max), k);  
  }

 }
```

Comment: An anonymous user submitted an edit suggestion replacing `string name=Integer.parseInt(w[1]);` with `string name=w[1];` with the comment *"you are doing the integer parsing of String class, it is no needed here."* I'm not approving anonymous code edits, though it looks to me like an improvement.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass values from mapper like {raj,8000 kiran,6000 john,9000} , so key will be constant , in following code you can check how it can be done ,

```
 public class MyMap extends Mapper<LongWritable,Text,Text,Text>    
   {  
     public void map(LongWritable k,Text v, Mapper<LongWritable,Text,Text,Text>.Context 
     con)throws IOException, InterruptedException  
   {  
     String line = v.toString();  
     String[] w=line.split(","); 
     String name = w[1] ; 
    int sal=Integer.parseInt(w[3]);  
    String map_op = name+","+sal ; 
    con.write(new Text("ds"), new Text(map_op)); 
    //ds {raj,8000 kiran,6000 john,9000}

    }  
   }
```

after shuffling and sorting "//ds {raj,8000 kiran,6000 john,9000}"

This will be the result,here we are passing ds as key ,

Now let's have a look at reducer method

```
    public class MyRed extends Reducer<Text,Text,IntWritable,Text>  
{  

      //ds {raj,8000 kiran,6000 john,9000}

 public void reduce(Text k, Iterable<Text> vlist, Reducer<Text,Text,IntWritable,Text>.Context con)
 throws IOException , InterruptedException  
    {  
     int max=0;  
     String name = k.toString() ;

     for(Text v: vlist)  
  {

         int salary = Integer.parseInt(v.toString().split(",")[1]) ;
         max=Math.max(max, salary); 

         if(salary == max)
        {
            name = v.toString().split(",")[0] ;
        }
  }  

  con.write(new IntWritable(max), new Text(name));  
 }
}
```

//9000 john :- This o/p will be produced by reducer